# How to debug code in NuGet package created by me

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet package I created and installed in another solution but now I need to debug the code of the package when called from my new solution.

I tried referencing the solution of the package but it's not working.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: related: [How to debug into my nuget package deployed from TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21857780/33499)

Comment: All you need is just a local NuGet source. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74310562) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020217) answer.

Answer (score 84):

To debug any dll you need the symbol file of it (.pdb). If you build your project in the `debug` configuration you will see that those files are generated and put in the build output folder.

Visual studio loads those symbol files from different places as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383798/6583901). The easiest way to debug your nuget packages is to put the .pdb files of the packages in the build output folder of the project you want to debug.

---

If the code you are trying to debug is classified as non-user code you need to ***uncheck*** `Just My Code` in the debugging options.

[image]

The following quote from the [Microsoft - Visual Studio Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code) shows what counts as user and what as non-user code.

> **User and non-user code**
>
> To distinguish user code from non-user code, Just My Code looks at
> symbol (.pdb) files and program optimizations. The debugger considers
> code to be non-user code when the binary is optimized or when the .pdb
> file is not available.
>
> Three attributes also affect what the debugger considers to be My
> Code:
>
> - DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute tells the debugger that the code it is applied to is not My Code.
> - DebuggerHiddenAttribute hides the code from the debugger, even if Just My Code is turned off.
> - DebuggerStepThroughAttribute tells the debugger to step through the code it is applied to, rather than step into the code.
>
> All other code is considered to be user code.

A more detailed answer can be found [on my blog](https://ntfrex.com/article/60108cb8b4f2a3608c38533f).

Comment: From every other crazy solution I have tried and wasted my time with this is the simplest. I just extract my `nuget.symbols.nupkg` and dump the pdb in the bin directory next to the downloaded dll , un-check `Enable just my code`  and I can step into my NuGet package. I did not even need to add the source files into the solution "Debug Source Files" panel. I don't understand why everybody suggested over the top, extremely complicated solutions? +1 for you mate!

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks for the information about `Enable just my code`. I've updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: I have tried this again on another project and it says the source code is missing.. so last time I included the source in the properties and it worked but this new project I didnt so I cannot step into the code - But you will also get "source code missing" when trying to step in.. you can then click "navigate to source" and select the folder with all the source files (in my case unpacked from the nuget package) boom - stepped into code. Another way is to just open the file in Visual Studio. File -> Open (the exact source file)

Comment: If I switch _Enable Just My Code_ off, I end up having to step through a bunch of .NET framework stuff before I get anywhere near my code.  It's not ideal, but disabling _Optimize code_ when building the NuGet package is the only reasonable option for me.  Just have to remember to switch it back for deployment.

Comment: Copied without attribution from https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2015

Comment: is this supposed to work with Net Core 3.1 ?

Answer (score 28):

For a nuget package source code hosted on GitHub or BitBucket:

1. To enable automatic source download and stepping for your nuget package dll, add nuget package `SourceLink.Create.CommandLine` to your project, or add it manually into *.csproj file:

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="SourceLink.Create.CommandLine" Version="2.8.2" PrivateAssets="All" /> 
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   More info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/).
2. In tools - options - debugging, disable `Enable Just My Code`, enable `Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed Only)`, and enable `Prevent using precompiled images on module load (Managed only, resets on restart)`. When a module is JIT optimized, the code being executed is slightly different (optimized) than the source code (e.g. some small methods might be inlined, etc), and stepping in the debugger would not reflect lines of code exactly. When precompiled images are used, it sometimes does not show variable values.
3. Only for Visual Studio 2017 and potentially older versions (this step is not needed since Visual Studio 2019, thx @alex-klaus ): Enable full debug information in *.csproj file:

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
     <DebugType>full</DebugType>
     <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

   or right-click project properties, build, advanced, output debugging information - set to full.

After this, you should be able to step into methods of a nuget package dll.

Comment: This is a great answer! SourceLink has been taken over by microsoft now so heres the new repo https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/. The only bummer is this requires packagereference and .NET Core.

Comment: What does `Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed Only)` do?

Comment: When the package is JIT optimized, the code being executed is slightly different (optimized) than the source code (e.g. some small methods might be inlined, etc), and stepping in the debugger would not reflect lines of code exactly.

Comment: Step 1 is [not required since Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980908/968003).

Comment: Great answer!! It works for my debugging with Castle.Core. +1

Answer (score 22):

There is a much simpler solution:

[image]

Simply embed the debug symbols in the dll. Update your nupkg, et voila!

Comment: The above is VS 2022 , in case the UI looks a little unfamiliar.

Comment: This will set the DebugType property to embedded

```<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>```

But there is something missing. you must also disable `Enable Just My Code`. After that things work great!

Answer (score 18):

I got this working by building the project the nuget package originated from in debug mode, then just copying the pdb and dll from the debug directory to the location of the nuget dll within the project I wanted to debug it in.

e.g copy from

ExternalNugetPackage\bin\Debug\

to

ProjectDirectory\Packages\ExternalNugetPackage.1.0.0\lib\net4.5

Answer (score 10):

> How to debug code in a nuget package created by me

Just as NtFreX answered, "*To debug any dll you need the symbol file of it (.pdb).* ". So you can create symbol packages which allow consumers to step into your package code in the Visual Studio debugger.

The way we do it (and works):

1. Create "*.symbols.nupkg".
2. Deploy symbol package to SymbolSource server.
3. Configure IDE, Package consumers can add https://nuget.smbsrc.net/ to your symbol sources in Visual Studio.
4. Add required Library to project using NuGet (from our SymbolSource server).
5. Debug.

For the detail info, you can refer to [Creating symbol packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages).

If these packages are not suitable for publishing on NuGet Gallery/SymbolSource, you can put the *.nupkg and *.symbols.nupkg files on a local disk.

Note: Add the source code to the Debug Source Files for the solution that references the package(Right click on Solution, select Properties...Common Properties...Debug Source Files, and add the root source directory for the relevant binary reference)

Comment: This just does not work- I have no idea why.. but I have spent too much time trying to figure it out when it should be simple for us. Putting the pdb file in the bin directory of the built project.. worked straight away for me (just had to un-check Enable My Code"

Answer (score 2):

As it might help someone else, here is an additional explanation of the problem in-hand.

What do I need to debug a pkg created by me?

1. As others here said. the *.pdb* file.
2. Also, the **source code** as expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597750/is-it-possible-to-debug-into-a-dll-with-only-a-pdb-and-no-source-code).

Well, how can I include the source code of my nuget package?

- I got to include the symbol packages. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821761/show-source-code-of-my-nuget) showed me how.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by packing the package in debug mode and installing it from my local NuGet source. Then when you debug you can step into your library. You can add your NuGet local source that points to your local folder in `Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources`

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 you can decompile needed source code to symbol file. This may become handy when you cannot load necessary PDB file. Debug -> Windows -> Modules

[image]

After dll is decompiled you can locate its content in Solution Explorer under External Sources. Click on the mylibrary.dll and you will see the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a simple solution without the need of replacing the NuGet package references in your project, and without the need of changing the settings in Visual Studio.

All you need to do, is just run the commands:

1. Pack the NuGet package with embedded debug symbols:

   ```
   dotnet pack -o ../LocalNuGetSource /p:DebugType=Embedded
   ```
2. Add your local NuGet source:

   ```bash
   dotnet nuget add source "PATH_TO_DIRECTORY" -n local
   ```

   Replace `PATH_TO_DIRECTORY` with the absolute path to your `LocalNuGetSource` directory.

Your package will appear in the `LocalNuGetSource` folder located at the same level as your dependency project.
Also, `Enable Just My Code` setting in Visual Studio does not need to be unchecked when using the Debug configuration, which is the default if no configuration is specified with the `-c` option in the `dotnet pack` command. The code of the resulting package should be considered as user code. Read about user code and non-user code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022.

In your main project, consider running the following commands to clean your project solution, clear the NuGet cache and restore the packages if you have previously configured a different NuGet source:

```bash
dotnet clean
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
dotnet restore
```