# nuget gallery versions and github

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

If I go to nuget gallery and search for a package e.g. Newtonsoft.Json

And I see a version available e.g. as of today `11.0.1-beta3 (current version)`

I then go to github for the project. In this case:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

I look at releases  and Tags and only see the "latest" which is `10.0.3`

My question is where is `11.0.1-beta3 (current version)`?

And how do I see what in it? e.g. I want to see if an issue has been fixed and is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Release Differences

`Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3` is the latest / current **Stable Release**.

`Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1-beta3` is the latest / current **Beta Release**.

You can locate the `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1-beta3` in the Nuget Gallery by scrolling down to the "Version History" section. Or just visit [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/11.0.1-beta3).

### Source Code

Regarding taking a peek at the code, since it is indeed open-source software, you can view the release notes and download the source-code from the [Github Release page](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases), as you saw. But of course only release versions will be listed here -- beta versions, still being a work-in-progress, will not.

Other than just installing the 11.0.1-beta3 package and inspecting the Newtonsoft.Json files in your IDE, you may be able to step through the source code in the Nuget Package following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821761/show-source-code-of-my-nuget). Not sure why you would, but if that's what you need go for it!

### Screenshots

[image: Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Gallery - 11.0.1]
[image: Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Version History]